# Estimating non-constant error function in a linear regression model?

Tags: regression, heteroscedasticity, nonlinear-regression

Consider the non-linear regression model:
$$
Y_i = g_1(X_i) + g_2(X_i) \varepsilon_i,
$$
where $g_1,g_2$ are unknown, $X_i, \varepsilon_i$ are i.i.d. random variables with $X_i$ and $e_j$ independent for all $i$ and $j$, and the $\varepsilon_i$ have mean zero and unit variance. This is the one-dimensional version of  equation (1) in [this](https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/pdf/10.1111/j.1467-9469.2011.00762.x?casa_token=I9zSIBFkFcgAAAAA:KI6r1zwIyAo4UHPEePDUlI_Zey1NZrQVgRGnOPiokYqpcYC68TyQPAqVqw9GeB8kVa9Y1eh2d5y67Q) paper.

We can estimate $g_1$ with the Nadaraya-Watson estimator:
$$
\tilde g_1(x) =\frac{\sum_{i=1}^n K_h(X_i)Y_i}{\sum_{i=1}^n \sum_{i=1}^n K_h(X_i)},
$$
where $K_h(X_i) = h^{-1} K((x-X_i)/h$ where $h$ is the bandwidth. (equation (6) in the paper).

In equation (9) the paper says $g_2$ can be estimated with
$$
\tilde g_2(x) = \sqrt{\frac{\sum_{i=1}^n Y_i^2 K_h(X_i)Y_i}{\sum_{i=1}^n \sum_{i=1}^n K_h(X_i)} - \tilde g_1^2(x)} .
$$

I have two questions, with the second being the most important:

1. Where is the expression for $\tilde g_2(x)$ coming from?
2. $\tilde g_1$ and $\tilde g_2$ allow us to estimate the $g_1$ and $g_2$ in the non-linear regression model where the error is non-constant. Can we do something similar when, instead of a general non-linear regression model, we consider a linear model for the predictors, with a non-constant error?
   $$
   Y_i = \beta_o + \beta_1 X_i + g_2(X_i) \varepsilon_i.
   $$
   In particular, is there an expression for estimating $g_2$ in this case?